# Display json type data from MySQL to Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am having trouble displaying data from my MySQL json-type column.

**Controller**

```
public function index()
    {
        $layaways = Layaway::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();

        $layaways = paginate($layaways);

        return view('admin/layaway.index')->with('layaways', $layaways);
    }
```

**View**

```
<tbody>
    @foreach ($layaways as $layaway)
         <tr data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#id{{ $layaway->transaction_id }}">
              <td>{{ $layaway->transaction_id }}</td>
         </tr>

         <td colspan="4" id="id{{ $layaway->transaction_id }}" class="collapse p-0" data-parent="#accordion">
              <div class="row ml-0 mr-0">
                   <div class="card col-md-6 pr-0 pl-0">
                       <div class="card-header text-center">
                          Layaway Products
                       </div>
                       <div class="card-body m-5">
                          @foreach ($layaway->selected_products as $product)
                             {{ $product->id }}
                          @endforeach
                       </div>
                   </div>
              </div>
          </td>
      @endforeach
</tbody>
```

**Sample data from dd()**

[image: sample data from dd]

**Sample data from dd() after Tharaka Dilhsan suggested**

[image]

**Error received**

```
Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
```

**Question**

- How can I properly display the json data which is inside the attribute field?

Answer (score 1):

You can use 'Casting' in 'Eloquent Model'

**Layway Model**

```
class Layway extends Model
{
    protected $casts = [
        'selected_peoducts' => 'array'
    ];
}
```

this will automattically cast your 'selecred_products' json data to an array.

Comment: I tried the answer you've provided but unfortunately, it returns an error
`htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given`...

I also tried to insert a new record after applying changes that you have recommend based on your answer, and it changes the format of the data. It appears that it has a `slash` on each of the beginning.

Comment: as the screenshot of `dd()` you have provided in the question, 'selected_products' is a string, not an array. can you provide the `dd()` output with this approach please.

Comment: I added an image on my post above. Sorry for late feedback. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
return view('admin/layaway.index')->with('layaways', $layaways->toArray());
```

Answer (score 0):

your inner array considers as a string so please convert the inner string to array and then try hope it's working.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working after a trial and error with tremendous research.

I just wrapped the `$layaway->selected_products` using `json_decode()`. Thank you.

**From this**

```
<div class="card-body m-5">
    @foreach ($layaway->selected_products as $product)
       {{ $product->id }}
    @endforeach
</div>
```

**To this**

```
<div class="card-body m-5">
    @foreach (json_decode($layaway->selected_products) as $product)
       {{ $product->id }}
    @endforeach
</div>
```